# Tweepy update_status missing required parameter: status, even though I am passing the status paramater

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am using Tweepy and trying to post a tweet to the authenticated users account.

I have a method:

```
def sendTweet(s):
    api.update_status(status=s)
```

which I am calling as `sendTweet("Some text")`

But whenever I do, it returns:

```
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Missing required parameter: status.', u'code': 170}]
```

In the Tweepy documentation it only says that to post a tweet you just do `api.update_status(s)`, but I saw in another question here that people had success when doing `api.update_status(status=s)`, but I'm not having success either way.

I tried updating Tweepy with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

had the same problem.
I solved it by entering:

```
 if line.strip():    
        api.update_status(status=line)
```